# Toolbar is not saving it's state in SwiftUI macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, toolbar

I have a simple app with the sidebar. ToolbarCommands are enabled, so people can customize toolbar as they wish. Toolbar is resetting to it's default state when customizing is done and person navigate to another section in the sidebar. How to keep person's changes?

Please check the video with the issue [here](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0X0kMYMApj9m9pwIXcgyC4GbQ#toolbar-issue).

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestSidebarApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                SidebarView()
                ContentView()
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 500, minHeight: 300)
        }
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands()
            ToolbarCommands()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .navigationTitle("My Application")
        .toolbar(id: "Jpjc8GMi") {
            ToolbarItem(id: "9vTvHYnT", placement: .automatic) {
                Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "archivebox") })
            }
            ToolbarItem(id: "GjzwKktt", placement: .automatic) {
                Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "trash") })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @State private var isDefaultItemActive = true
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(), isActive: $isDefaultItemActive) {
                Label("First Item", systemImage: "folder")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                Label("Second Item", systemImage: "folder")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .toolbar(id: "nX6tYuxN") {
            ToolbarItem(id: "Gp22fv5N", placement: .automatic) {
                Spacer()
            }
            ToolbarItem(id: "EuRxyg4s", placement: .automatic) {
                Button(action: {}, label: { Image(systemName: "plus") })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to safe your users change. One option would be "Userdefaults". https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults?language=objc

Comment: @Osman but what I should store here?

Comment: I guess the problem is not in the UserDefaults. Changes will be saved if you edit toolbar items, then relaunch the app. Seems like a bug to me