# How to use NSToolbar in SwiftUI lifecycle

Tags: macos, swiftui, nstoolbar

I tried to implement an editable toolbar in SwiftUI and hit a bug. User's changes simply resets to its defaults. I'm looking to implement NSToolbar in SwiftUI lifecycle. How to handle editable NSToolbar in swiftui-like style with support 2 or 3 columns layout?

[image]

Comment: "What is the best way to..."  Nobody can answer that type of questions.

Comment: @ElTomato Changed. Thanks

Comment: You can’t use NSToolbar with the SwiftUI lifecycle, you’d need to switch to the older app delegate lifecycle. 

That said, your SwiftUI toolbar bug may be fixable, if you want to share your code for that…?

Comment: @Adam Got it! My doubts was how to attach nstoolbar to the window, because window is managing with swiftui…

Comment: @Adam The issue is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921583/toolbar-is-not-saving-its-state-in-swiftui-macos). I will be very grateful if you can take a look

Comment: @RomanBanks Oh yeah, that’s an ugly bug. I think you may be out of luck with the SwiftUI lifecycle.

Comment: @Adam Fortunately I'm not too far to switch lifecycle. Thank you!